# Sortable inside list, draggable outside (movable anywhere)

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make sortable list panel docked on the bottom of page, 
also I want some items from the list to be draggable anywhere on the screen
and if they are moved back to the list they will be sortable (docked and sorted).

I am using jquery.

Comment: Read up on [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/home). The tags you've mentioned are covered in it. Do some work and post what you've done first.

Comment: Just saw kei's comment and I totally agree- please add more information.  Community can only help you as much as you help yourself and in this case that is by explaining what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be looking at the [jQuery UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

Take a look at a [docking tool](http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/) as well.

You can tie into events that will allow you to automatically sort them.

"I want some items from the list to be draggable anywhere on the screen" and what would they do then?

Maybe if you could clarify what you want to see happen or maybe find a similiar offering online we can help you get pointed in the right direction

Comment: I din´t find anything alike there. OK.
There is panel at the bottom of the page. fixed.
In panel there are some kinds of stuff, some are movable some not.
What I want to do is, when you drag movable parts of this panel outside of it, they stay where you moved them. And then when you drag them back to the panel they will be threated like sortable.

Comment: Take a look at something like: http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.containerPlus/demo/demo.html in combination with jquery docking.  Maybe someone else will have a better suggestion.

Comment: Only issue I am facing is how to make item in sortable list draggable after it is moved outside panel (div) and after moving this item back to panel disable draggable.
I tried it with $(#panel div id).mouseenter(function() { $(movable item class).draggable(disabled: true)}); and disable : false on mouseleave event...but with no effect